# Image loop in lightbox not working correct

Tags: php, html

I am trying to loop 83 images in a lightbox, so I don't have to add them all in HTML.
But when I loop them with PHP I get a gallery-view of broken images(not exactly what I want, I want them to show 1 image and when clicked show all other images in the lightbox, but that's not really urgent now). They got this path when i inspect element:

```
<img src="afbeeldingen/slides/dias/afbeeldingen/slides/thumbs">
```

So I figured something went wrong in the loop, but I don't know what.

When I click the first image the lightbox works, but not for the other images.

The images are in afbeeldingen/slides/dias called Dia1.JPG to Dia83.JPG and they have thumbnails in the path: afbeeldingen/slides/thumbs called thumbDia1.jpg to thumbDia83.jpg

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
$dirname = 'afbeeldingen/slides/dias/';
$thumbs = 'afbeeldingen/slides/thumbs';
$images = scandir($dirname);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");

foreach($images as $curimg){
    if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
        echo '<ul id="auto-loop" class="gallery">
                <li data-src="'.$dirname.$curimg.'"> 
                    <a href="#">
                    <img src="'.$dirname.$thumbs.'" />
                    </a> 
                </li>
            </ul>';
    }
}
```

This is the plain html that works with the lightbox, but I don't want to do this for 83 images:

```
<ul id="auto-loop" class="gallery">
    <li data-src="afbeeldingen/slides/dias/Dia1.JPG"> 
        <a href="#">
        <img src="afbeeldingen/slides/dias/dia1thumb.jpg" />
        </a> 
    </li>
    <li data-src="img2.jpg" > 
        <a href="#">
        <img src="thumb2.jpg" />
        </a> 
    </li>
    <li data-src="img3.jpg"> 
        <a href="#">
        <img src="thumb3.jpg" />
        </a> 
    </li>
    <li data-src="img4.jpg" > 
        <a href="#">
        <img src="thumb4.jpg" />
        </a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can someone help me on the correct way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding `ul` tag in foreach,which generates multiple ul's with single li's in it, so, place it out of the loop, as :

```
...
//store your <ul> in a variable
$ul = '<ul id="auto-loop" class="gallery">';
foreach($images as $curimg){
    if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
        //add li's to your ul
        $ul .='<li data-src="'.$dirname.$curimg.'"> 
                    <a href="#">
                    <img src="'.$dirname.$thumbs.'" />
                    </a> 
                </li>';
    }
}
//finally close ul tag
$ul .='</ul>';
echo $ul; //display the <ul> tag
```

Comment: When I do that the images don't display anymore. Can't I just echo the <ul> outside the foreach?

Comment: Thank you! The lightbox works now, but the thumbnails are still not displayed correctly, I got a gallery view of broken images.

Comment: @user50248 check your image sources, may be its not proper

Comment: This is the imagepath <img src="afbeeldingen/slides/dias/afbeeldingen/slides/thumbs"> so no wonder it's not working, I just don't know for sure how to seperate the thumb path and image path in the loop, and then use them.